# Adding a base class in c++ template specialization

Tags: c++, templates

In the dusty corners of a code base I work on, I've come across a class hierarchy that looks like this:

```
class Base1
{
  int base1;
};

class Base2
{
  int base2;
};
template <typename T> class A : public Base1
{
      T _specialT;
};
template <> class A<int> : public Base2
{
      int _special;
};
```

The use of Base2 in the specialization of A is something that surprised me.  I've been searching around to understand exactly what it means, haven't been able to find any examples or discussions of this sort of design.

It seems to me that what this does is cause A to inherit from both Base1 and Base2 while other uses of A that are not specialized will inherit from only Base1.  That leaves me with a couple of questions:

1. Do I understand this correctly?
2. Are there any non-obvious caveats
   in added to the hierarchy this way? Why would you do this?
3. Are there times when this would be considered good design?

Comment: Uhm, what exactly do you want to achieve by this?

Comment: This is existing code that I encountered, I'm just trying to understand it and understand what might have been the reasoning behind this implementation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. No. The primary class template inherits from `Base1` and only the `<int>` specialization inherits from `Base2` (and from `Base2` only).

Not knowing the context where this is used, I can't answer 2. or 3.

You can often see specializations deriving from different types in template meta-programming. For example:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
struct is_same : std::false_type {};

template<typename T>
struct is_same<T,T> : std::true_type {};
```

It's perfectly valid thing to do. Whether it is a good thing to do depends entirely on the problem being solved.

Comment: There are generally rules of thumb that can be applied to design choices (ie use inheritance for isa relationships).  I realize you can't comment on my specific situation, but are their some rules that would apply to when to use (or not use) this approach?

Comment: @MattG There are no specific rules, except the ones that apply everywhere in programming: Write things in such a way that a maintainer has best chances to understand your intents. Keep surprises to a minimum, don't do things overly fancy. And wrt "inheritance = is-a": that applies to object-orientation. But C++ templates are a feature orthogonal to OO, and can benefit from inheritance as well, so that rule does not completely apply, e.g. when it comes to TMP

Answer (score 2):

A specialization of a template is completely independent, code-wise, from the normal case. So `A<int>` will not derive from both `Base1` and `Base2`, just from `Base2`.

There are certainly cases where specializations are good design. Whether this is one is not possible to tell from your abstracted example, of course.

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind that different instantiations of class templates are different, independent classes. Specializations of templates do not add things to the general case, they replace it completely.

Thus, `A<int>` is a class that derives from `Base2` and has one int member named `_special`, `A<double>` and `A<char>` are two independent, different classes that both happen to derive from `Base1` and each have one member of type double and char, respectively, named `_specialT`.

So:

1. It seems from your question that you did *not* understand it correctly.
2. There are caveats, especially if specializations are defined not directly after the basic template but in another part. It will come as a suprise if a maintainer sees the general definition of A and tries to use some methods of `Base1` on an `A<int>` (or use the `_specialT` member), getting compiler errors because he did not see the specialization. A very popular example is the specialization of `std::vector<bool>` in the standard wich behaves differently from the "normal" `std::vector` and is widely considered broken.
3. There can be times where some people consider this good design, sometimes a design like this is even considered good by *many* people. However, design sometimes is a matter of taste, and when it comes to templates and their not-so-typical use cases, many people consider unexpected things like different base classes in specializations as bad style or at least "black template magic", e.g. when it's used in template meta programming.

This pattern (specializations deriving from different bases) is often used in Template Metaprogramming. A (very) simple example:

```
template <class T>
struct is_int_or_double : std::false_type
{};

template <>
struct is_int_or_double<int> : std::true_type //another base class!
{};

template <>
struct is_int_or_double<double> : std::true_type //another base class!
{};
```